# Wildcards and VBA on Rockwell FactoryTalk View SE

Tags: vba

I'm extremely new to VBA (I did 3 weeks of it in grade 9, but that's about it). I'm an industrial PLC programmer by trade, but one of my applications has required me to unearth the painful memories of grade 9 IT for a Rockwell FactoryTalk View SE SCADA system.

My application is that there is a server, which stores graphic display, and multiple clients, which display these graphic displays. Depending on which client is being used, I want to make certain items visible or invisible to the user. I can do that in a basic sense, but I'm wondering if there's a more efficient way. Here's the code as it stands:

```
Private Sub Display_AnimationStart()
Dim HostName As String
HostName = Environ$("computername")
Select Case HostName
    Case "CCSPE1X2"
        Elements.Item("VBAControl_X2Only").Visible = True
    Case "CCSPE1X3"
        Elements.Item("VBAControl_X3Only").Visible = True
    End Select
End Sub
```

This all works; I just group everything that should only be visible to the X2 client into a group called "VBAControl_X2Only", etc. But that then makes the graphic editor painful to work with, as there are bits and pieces from all over the display piled into one group, separated from the rest of the groups they should really belong to. I've decided that I'm better to take them out of the one big group and just add each item individually to the VBA code.

Then I thought, what if there's a way to use wildcards here? So any item that should only be visible on CCSPE1X2, I name "StartButton_X2Only" or "StopButton_X2Only", etc. And then I run a search for any items whose name ends with "X2Only", and make it invisble.

Im envisioning something like:

```
Dim ElementName As String
        If Elements.Item("*").Name Like "*X2Only" Then
            ElementName = Elements.Item("*").Name
            Elements.Item(ElementName).Visible = True
        End If
```

That doesn't work (I didn't really expect it to honestly); when it gets to If Elements.Item("*") it gives error 91 - object variable or with block variable not set.

Can anyone tell me if I'm close to the mark? Or if it's impossible? I don't even know if there's a way to make it search every item on the display, as it's not just an excel spreadsheet where I could tell it to search a column.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to iterate through all of the individual Items. Try something like this:

```
    For Each Item In Elements
        If Item.Name Like "*X2Only" Then
            Item.Visible = True
        End If
    Next Item
```